# Another way to load remote data in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get the remote using json from one php page,the JSON data:

```
[{"id":"0","name":"ABC"},{"id":"1","name":"DEF I"},{"id":"2","name":"GHI"}]
```

and the script is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        placeholder: 'Search',
        ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "subject/data_json.php",
        data: function (term, page) {// page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
            return {
                college: "ABC", //search term
                term: term
            };
        },
        type: 'GET',
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(data) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + data.name + "</div>"; 
        },
        formatSelection: function(data) {
            return data.name;
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
            callback({"name":elementText});
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine but it always reads the database whenever I typed one new character to search
. So i decided to use the another way (retrieve all data at first time and use select2 to search it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").select2({
        createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { 
        if ($(data).filter(function() { 
        return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {
        return {id:term, text:term};} 
    },
    multiple: false,
    data: [{"id":"0","text":"ABC"},{"id":"1","text":"DEF I"},{"id":"2","text":"GHI"}]
    });
});
```

But the problem is how can I pass a request to data_json.php and retrieve data from it?
Say

```
data: $.ajax({
            url: "subject/data_json.php",
            data: function (term, page) {// page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
                return {
                    college: "ABC", //search term
                };
            }
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                return data
            }
        }
```

But its not working, can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you move away from your original code?

```
minimumInputLength: 1
```

Increase this and the search won't be called on the first character typed. Setting it to 3 for example will ensure the ajax call isn't made (and the database therefore not queried) until after the 3rd character is entered.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly you have data_json.php generating the options for select2 and you would like to load all of them once instead of having select2 run an ajax query each time the user inputs one or more characters in the search.

This is how I solved it in a similar case.
**HTML:**

```
<span id="mySelect"></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax('/path/to/data_json.php', {
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
      $("#mySelect").select2({
        data: response
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I've found that the above does not work if you create a `<select>` element instead of a `<span>`.